# How do you add a resource to a .bundle/wrapper.plug-in?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, embedded-resource

Sorry for the n00b question, but I have no more hair to pull. =(

I'm building my iOS project using XCode and have a reference to another XCode project, to make this work I also need to reference the bundle-file. The developer who built the project and bundle wanted to organize things and thus put all the images inside of this .bundle-file.

Now my question is this:

**How do you add a file/resource to a .bundle file?** -> http://grab.by/7p3Y

The file type of the bundle is: wrapper.plug-in -> http://grab.by/7p3W

The files I add by right-clicking and selecting add existing files all end up in the project not in the bundle resource.

Any kind of help will be most appreciated! Also an indication if this is common or a custom solution?

Best regards
Abeansits

**Update:**

As usual the problem was me, I'm blaming this on low sugar levels. =(
All you need to do is add a file to the bundle manually and it will show up in XCode.

Comment: I'll wait for somebody more expert with Xcode, but AFAIK, you can't add files to already built products, you can only add them to projects.  So if you own the project that builds the bundle, add the files there. You can use cross-project references if you need to use a bundle built by one project inside another project.  Like I say, let's wait for the more experienced Xcode guys though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the question, the solution is really simple. Just add the files you need inside the project to the bundle. Since the bundle is actually a folder, you can right click it an select show content. Anything you later add to the folder will show up in the project.

I guess this confused me since usually when you add resources to your project you need to do this through XCode.

Comment: Although this sounds like a noob question it still points out something that behaves funny: go to Finder, open package contents, drag new file to bundle, file copies, check XCode project: file's not there; in Finder close and show package contents again: file's not there anymore either. In Finder, show package contents second time, drag and drop file again, close package contents, open it again: file is there. Return to xcode: file's there this time. Does closing the "package contents" in the folder trigger a write or something? Needs investigation...

Comment: Why the down vote? My answer gives a response to the questions mentioned above. If there is a bug in your particular setup that should not invalidate the answer...

Comment: Can I assume the "why down vote" question is a question to the public at large? I didn't down vote, but in my inbox it looks like you're asking me the question.